# Linked in page is not showing in app

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

I have integrated linked in authentication in my application.
It was working fine but today its not loading a page in my app's web view.
I am getting response as below for access token:
API Response::::****************

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x1468fa30> { URL: https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken } { status code: 400, headers {
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Encoding" = gzip;
"Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
Date = "Tue, 25 Nov 2014 07:11:16 GMT";
Server = "Apache-Coyote/1.1";
"Set-Cookie" = "lidc=\"b=LB83:g=130:u=1:i=1416899476:t=1416985876:s=2341738268\"; Expires=Wed, 26 Nov 2014 07:11:16 GMT; domain=.linkedin.com; Path=/";
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
"Www-Authenticate" = "OAuth realm=\"https%3A%2F%2Fapi.linkedin.com\", oauth_problem=\"timestamp_refused\", oauth_acceptable_timestamps=\"1416899476%2B-900\"";
"X-FS-UUID" = 4ff0ed1a91d6a913f0761484b22a0000;
"X-LI-UUID" = "T/DtGpHWqRPwdhSEsioAAA==";
"X-Li-Fabric" = "PROD-ELA4";
"X-Li-Pop" = "prod-nsg7";
```

} }

Please reply soon.

Code to fech user profile from linked in :

```
self.consumer = [[OAConsumer alloc] initWithKey:LINKEDIN_APIKEY
                                         secret:LINKEDIN_SECRETKEY
                                          realm:@"http://api.linkedin.com/"];


requestTokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken"]
  linkedInCallbackURL = LINKEDIN_LINKEDINCALLBACKURL;

OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:requestTokenURL
                                                               consumer:self.consumer
                                                                token:nil
                                                               callback:linkedInCallbackURL
                                                                signatureProvider:nil];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

OARequestParameter *nameParam = [[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"scope"
                                                                   value:@"r_basicprofile+r_emailaddress"];
NSArray *params = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nameParam, nil];
[request setParameters:params];
OARequestParameter * scopeParameter=[OARequestParameter requestParameter:@"scope" value:@"r_fullprofile r_emailaddress"];

[request setParameters:[NSArray arrayWithObject:scopeParameter]];

OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];
[fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                     delegate:self
            didFinishSelector:@selector(requestTokenResult:didFinish:)
              didFailSelector:@selector(requestTokenResult:didFail:)];
```

web view method to load linked in :

```
    - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *url = request.URL;
    NSString *urlString = url.absoluteString;

    BOOL requestForCallbackURL = ([urlString rangeOfString:linkedInCallbackURL].location != NSNotFound);
    if ( requestForCallbackURL )


     {
            BOOL userAllowedAccess = ([urlString rangeOfString:@"user_refused"].location == NSNotFound);
        if ( userAllowedAccess )
        {
            [self.requestToken setVerifierWithUrl:url];
            [self accessTokenFromProvider];
        }
        else
        {
            // User refused to allow our app access
            // Notify parent and close this view
            UIAlertView *alrt=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Linked In" message:@"App access denied by the user." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

            [alrt show];
            [webView removeFromSuperview];

        }
    }


    return YES;
    }
```

Comment: http status code is 400 means server didn't understand the request.can you post your code for sending a request to linked for authentication

Comment: But it was working fine before 1 month. Is there any changes I need to apply?

Comment: it could be like, linked required number of parameter,  app_id or client_id etc it's structure may changed by linked.

Comment: Please check I have added my request

Comment: If its working before 1Month. better option to check LinkedIn forum. Or post your question there. You will get solution with all the changes with in 48 hours

Comment: @PradipVanparia its working for ios 7 but not with ios 8.

Comment: Can anyone share link for linked in forum? I don't know where to post my question on linked in forum.

Comment: @Pooja. https://developer.linkedin.com/forum